# Spring Autowired field null on Test Helper Class

Tags: java, spring, cucumber

Structure..

```
src/test/java
 config
  TestConfiguration.java
 hooks
  WebDriverHooks.java
 nicebank
  RunSteps.java
  OtherSteps..
 support
  ATMUserInterface.java
  KnowsTheDomain.java
```

`@Autowired` is correctly injecting `KnowsTheDomain` when placed Steps in `nicebank` package. But I am unable to `@Autowired` `KnowsTheDomain` when placed in Helper classes such as `WebDriverHooks` and `ATMUserInterface`

Does it require configuring annotation when autowiring to different packages? I am running Cucumber runner..

From WebDriverHook.java and ATMUserInterface.java, the field `private KnowsTheDomain helper;` is returning null instead of singleton instance. I need them to return what it returns when I run Steps in `nicebank` package.

Anyone has idea why this `helper` field is null?

TestConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "support"})
public class TestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public static KnowsTheDomain knowsTheDomain() {
        return new KnowsTheDomain();
    }
}
```

WebDriverHooks.java

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@Configurable(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)
public class WebDriverHooks {
    @Autowired
    private KnowsTheDomain helper;

    @After
    public void finish(Scenario scenario) {
        try {
            byte[] screenshot = 
                        helper.getWebDriver().getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
        } catch (WebDriverException somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots) {
            System.err.println(somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            helper.getWebDriver().close();
        }
    }
}
```

RunSteps.java   - this runs the Cucumber runner..

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:out"},
        snippets = SnippetType.CAMELCASE,
        features = "classpath:cucumber",
        dryRun = false)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
public class RunSteps {

}
```

KnowsTheDomain.java

```
@Component
public class KnowsTheDomain {
    private Account myAccount;
    private CashSlot cashSlot;
    private Teller teller;
    private EventFiringWebDriver webDriver;

    public Account getMyAccount() {
        if (myAccount == null) {
            myAccount = new Account();
        }
        return myAccount;
    }
    public CashSlot getCashSlot() {
        if (cashSlot == null) {
            cashSlot = new CashSlot();
        }
        return cashSlot;
    }
    public Teller getTeller() {
        if (teller == null) {
            teller = new ATMUserInterface();
        }
        return teller;
    }
    public EventFiringWebDriver getWebDriver() {
        if (webDriver == null) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
            webDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(new ChromeDriver());
        }
        return webDriver;
    }
}
```

ATMUserInterface.java

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@Configurable(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)
public class ATMUserInterface implements Teller {
    @Autowired
    private KnowsTheDomain helper;

    @Override
    public void withdrawFrom(Account account, int dollars) {
        try {
            helper.getWebDriver().get("http://localhost:" + ServerHooks.PORT);
            helper.getWebDriver().findElement(By.id("Amount"))
                        .sendKeys(String.valueOf(dollars));
            helper.getWebDriver().findElement(By.id("Withdraw")).click();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("err" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Configurable` requires full AOP to be working, which requires a bit of setup. The best option is almost always to switch to constructor injection.

Answer (score 0):

@Autowired will work only in beans.

So make sure where are you using @Autowired annotation.

Add hooks package to @ComponentScan as below

> @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "support", "hooks" })